# FragmentPagerAdapter never getItem() never gets called

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I have spent 2 hours trying to solve the problem. The code worked yesterday, but when I tried to run `ViewPager` today it just wouldn't display the fragments. After debugging I noticed that `getcount()` inside my `FragmentPagerAdapter` gets called, but my `getItem()` never does. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

My `ViewPagerFragment` class:

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {


public static final String ARGS_KEY="schedules";


 ViewPager mViewPager;
ArrayList<Schedule> mSchedules;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager,container,false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);

    mViewPager= (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mSchedules= Parcels.unwrap(getArguments().getParcelable(ARGS_KEY));

    final ArrayList<Fragment> fragments=setupFragments(mSchedules);
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter=ViewPagerAdapter.initializeWithFragmentList(fragments,getChildFragmentManager());

    mViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    return view;
}


private ArrayList<Fragment> setupFragments(ArrayList<Schedule> Schedules ){
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments=new ArrayList<>();

    for (Schedule schedule:Schedules){
        ViewPagerItemFragment fragment= createViewPagerItem(schedule);
        fragments.add(fragment);
    }

    return fragments;
}

public  ViewPagerItemFragment createViewPagerItem(Schedule schedule){
    Checker.checkIfObjectNull(schedule);
    ViewPagerItemFragment viewPagerItemFragment=new ViewPagerItemFragment();
    setArgsForFragment(viewPagerItemFragment,schedule);

    return viewPagerItemFragment;
}

private ViewPagerItemFragment setArgsForFragment(ViewPagerItemFragment fragment,Schedule schedule){
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(ViewPagerItemFragment.ARGS_KEY,Parcels.wrap(schedule));
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}
```

My `ViewPagerAdapter` Class:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments;


public static ViewPagerAdapter initializeWithFragmentList(ArrayList<Fragment> fragments, FragmentManager fragmentManager){
    return new ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager,fragments);
}

private ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    mFragments=fragments;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need `initializeWithFragmentList` static  method. Make the constructor public. And if `mSchedules` is empty, then, yes, there's no fragments, so please debug your for loop there

Comment: @cricket_007 I've debugged the loop before and mSchedules is not null and fragments get created and passed on to the ViewPagerAdapter constructor. When debugged getCount()   MFragments.size() returns 3, and normally it should call getItem() 3 times after that, but it just never get's called. I have no idea what the problem is. Seems like the code should be working

Comment: Try to load more then three pages. Default viewpager behavior can load three Fragments into memory at once. Method doesn't need called again

Comment: @cricket_007 loading more pages didn't solve the problem and yes I looked at that question. The solutions provided there didn't solve my problem. Man maybe I should just rewrite the whole class from scratch and see if it works?

Comment: Just extending the other class doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah I tried extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Then problem persists.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest starting over, though. You said it was working, so what did you change? There's something going on at the XML or fragment level if you see nothing show up. I'm not sure what you're doing to see if that method is called or not, but it should be. Having Fragments in Fragments might mess with something

Comment: I set a break point on getItem() but the debugging never reached that method. Anyways I tried rewriting my classes and even xml, still the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem. It a silly thing really. I use genymotion emulator and for some reason it wasn't debugging my code correctly. Restating the emulator seems to have solved the issue.